# Find vertices and plot triangle in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

The vertices of triangle is given in `tri = [1 2 2 1; 1 2 -2 1]`

I see that tri has 4 columns and 2 rows, but how does they define the vertices?

What are the vertices defined in the tri and how to plot them in Matlab?

Comment: please show more explanations ? do you mean triplot ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `tri` variable, the last vertex is the same as the first. That makes sense if you want the triangle to be closed when you use `plot`. Compare the following:

```
tri = [1 2 2; 1 2 -2]; %// just the three vertices
plot(tri(1,:), tri(2,:), 'linewidth', 1)
axis([0 3 -3 3])
```

[image]

```
tri = [1 2 2 1; 1 2 -2 1]; %// first vertex is repeated to "close" the plot
plot(tri(1,:), tri(2,:), 'linewidth', 1)
axis([0 3 -3 3])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I was (hopefully right) informed from these unsufficiently cited data, I can judiciously assume that two dimensions of this array represent two axises, and data represents x, and y coordinates means your triangle passes through (exagerately) four verticles : `(1,1)`,`(2,2)`,`(2,-2)`,`(1,1)` where the last one is reduplicated.

You can plot your triangular shape using this command:

```
triplot(delaunay(tri(1,1:3),tri(2,1:3)),tri(1,1:3),tri(2,1:3))
```

[image]